# Several managed closures with shared state?

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a Rust wrapper for Expat XML parser.  I wrapped the start_element, end_element callbacks and they work fine in simple cases (e.g. just counting XML elements) as follows:

```
struct Expat {
  parser: expat::XML_Parser
}

type StartHandler = @fn(tag: &str, attrs: &[~str]);
type EndHandler = @fn(tag: &str);
type TextHandler = @fn(text: &str);

struct Handlers {
  start_handler: StartHandler,
  end_handler: EndHandler,
  text_handler: TextHandler
}

impl Expat {
  pub fn handlers(&self, start_handler: StartHandler, end_handler: EndHandler, text_handler: TextHandler) {
    let handlers = @Handlers {
      start_handler: start_handler,
      end_handler: end_handler,
      text_handler: text_handler
    };
    // How to do this properly?
    unsafe { cast::bump_box_refcount(handlers) };

    expat::XML_SetUserData(self.parser, unsafe { cast::transmute(&*handlers) });
}
```

I can pass simple managed closures to handlers() and have them update @mut uint values.

Now I want to maintain the current XPath across callbacks and am having problems:

```
let mut xpath: ~[~str] = ~[];
let xpath_start_handler: @fn(&str, &[~str]) = |tag: &str, _attrs: &[~str]| {
  vec::push(&xpath, tag.to_owned());
  println(fmt!("  start: %?", xpath));
};
let xpath_end_handler: @fn(&str) = |tag: &str| {
  println(fmt!("  end: %?", xpath));
  let top = vec::pop(&xpath);
  if top != tag.to_owned() {
    fail!(fmt!("expected end tag: %s, received end tag: %s", top, tag));
  }
};
let xpath_text_handler: @fn(&str) = |_text: &str| {
};
expat.handlers(xpath_start_handler, xpath_end_handler, xpath_text_handler);
```

The compiler says that the unique vector xpath was moved into the xpath_start_handler closure and cannot be accessed in xpath_end_closure.

So my question is what is the best way to maintain mutable state across many managed closures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared boxes should be managed, not unique:

```
let state: @mut ~[~str] = @mut ~[];
let push: @fn(~str) = |x| {
    vec::push(state, x);
};
let pop: @fn() -> ~str = || {
    vec::pop(state)
};
let count: @fn() -> uint = || {
    (&*state).len()
};
push(~"ho");
push(~"hey");
println(fmt!("%?", count()));
println(pop());
println(pop());
println(fmt!("%?", count()));
```

Also, mutable unique boxes work a bit differently than mutable managed boxes.

Comment: I did managed boxes for counting XML elements, and that worked fine.  However, in this case vec::push() absolutely insists on a mutable unique pointer.  Do I need to implement my own vector that works with managed pointers?

Comment: Wow, so simple: a unique box inside a managed box, and it works.  Thanks for help!